# Jquery.validate and jquery autocomplete conflicts

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I have some php with forms, they have been using jquery.validate.js for a while to do all the field validations with no problem.

Recently I wanted to introduce some autocomplete functionality, and bizarrely, when I include the scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_import/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_import/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js"></script>
```

While the validation still works and the form is not submitted, for some reason now, the form post is executed, the page is refreshed and the URL adds

```
?action=submit
```

That is acting differently and causing minor issues elsewhere in the code - ie, before adding those above scripts, when you click Submit, the page isn't refreshed and you don't get that re-loaded effect.

Has anyone seen this issue ?

Comment: Check your browser's console for the errors. When you get an exception in your script than the page gets refresh.

Comment: Does it occur when you add one of the scripts or only with both?

Comment: good point, i've only tried adding both - i will take a look at console errors when i get back to it